# check if the url has been finish loaded

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

From phonegap app, We are opening url in browser by this :

```
 var urlUs = 'http//blabla';
 window.open(urlUs, '_system');
```

My question is, is there a way to detect from the app if the open url has been fully/finished loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can try listening for the event loadstop like that :

```
var urlUs = 'http://blabla';
var w = window.open(urlUs, '_system');
w.addEventListener('loadstop', callbackComplete);
```

You can also listen for other events like loaderror or loadstart.

Comment: what does loadstop means here?

Comment: Can I make it like this :

var complete = w.addEventListener('loadstop', callbackComplete);

And then to check it if (complete) //do something

Comment: It is asynchronous, you can't (shouldn't) do it like this.
Since the loadstop event is dispatched when the loading is complete, then just do your stuff within the callbackComplete.